# Errors writing image gallery

Tags: javascript, image, gallery, undefined

I'm trying to write a simply image gallery element for a website and I'm having trouble with the code for silly reasons. I've never gotton on with JavaScript and have always found it a headache. I've tried various other image galleries but can't for the life of me get them to actually work correctly either

My current HTML code is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test of slider </title>     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slider" id="main">
            <img src="#" class="mainImage" />
            <div class="sliderImages" style="display: none;">
                <img src="companion.jpg"/>              
                <img src="cookie.jpg" />
                <img src="orange.jpg" />
                <img src="orangeWhole.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="sliderButtons">
                <a href="#" onclick="Slider.Slide('main', -1)"> Previous </a>
                <a href="#" onclick="Slider.Slide('main', 1)"> Next </a>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

with the javascript like this:

```
this.Slider = new function(){
// Stores the indices for each slider on the page, referenced by their ID's
var indices = {};
var limits = {};
var images = {};

// Call this function after a major DOM change/change of page
this.SetUp = function(){        
    // obtain the sliders on the page
    // TODO restrict to those within body
    var sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');
    // assign the indices for each slider to 0
    for(var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++){
        indices[sliders[i].id] = 0;
        var sliderImages = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderImages');
        var imagesTemp = sliderImages[0].getElementsByTagName('img');
        images[sliders[i].id] = imagesTemp;
        limits[sliders[i].id] = imagesTemp.length;
    }
}

// advances a certain slider by the given amount (usually 1 or -1)
this.Slide = function(id, additive){
    if(indices && id){
        indices[id] = indices[id] + additive;

        // Check limits
        if(indices[id] < 0){
            indices[id] = limits[id] - 1;
        }
        if(indices[id] >= limits[id]){
            indices[id] = 0;
        }

        // alter img to be the new index
        document.getElementById(id).getElementsByClassName('mainImage')[0].src = images[id][indices[id]].src;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var slider in sliders)
{
 // here slider is the index of the array. to get the object use sliders[slider]
}
```

then you can use  'getElementsByClassName' function

edit

1. U have included the slider.js on the top of the html. So first it loads the the js and tries to access the elements which are not yet created..Move the  tag to the bottom of the page.
2. sliderImages is an array of divs with classname  sliderImages. there is only one that satisfies.

   ```
   var sliderImages // is a array with 1 item.
                // to get the images use sliderImages[0].getElementsByTagName('img');
   ```
3. change

   ```
   this.Slide = new function(id, additive){
   ```

   to

   ```
   this.Slide = function(id, additive){ // otherwise it will be called when the page is loaded with undefined values.
   ```
4. onclick of the link call with quotes

   ```
   Slider.Slide('main', 1)
   ```

Comment: with the images, that would return too many images if I had more than one gallery or images elsewhere on the page, i need only those stored in the sliderImages div

Comment: I've altered the code to the current version,

Main problem is that var sliders doesn't actually have anything in it - it's not picking up the div at all

Comment: I've moved it down, but it still executes each function with null parameters, but I've put a check in for that.

now however Slider is undefined - this is really confusing as I've defined objects like that in the main code for the website and that has no such problems...

Comment: i told to remove new from this.Slide function only.. U removed from Slider class and setup function.. now they are never initialised.. Also u missed the closing bracket of Slider main function.

Comment: the js code in your jsFiddle doesn't work - i get an error because the list of sliders is empty - document.getElementsByClassName('slider') isn't working which is rather odd

Although it does if i remove the new from SetUp and call it in onload

I now have a working slider so far. Thank you

Comment: the only reason i could think of is still u are having the script tag above the content. Anyway u got the slider. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using  a methode I do not know (or you forgot the "s")

```
 var sliderImages = slider.getElementByClassName('sliderImages');
```

I would use something like the code below. It is important sliderImages will be an array of anything that is of the class "silderImages"

```
 var sliderImages  =slider.getElementsByClassName("sliderImages")
```

Comment: I've switched the line to that, was a simple typo - but I still have the problem that the line
    this.indices[slider.id] = 0;

is getting an error for "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'undefined' of undefined "